# Getting an error: {"message":"Invalid content type. Please send data as application/json"}

Tags: javascript, express, parsing

In my server.js i have this:

```
// app.use(express.json({ type: 'application/json' }));
app.use(express.json()); // Handles both JSON and urlencoded data
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // Parse extended (nested) objects
```

And in my HTML i have this code:

```
<script>
        const signupForm = document.getElementById('signupForm');
        
        signupForm.addEventListener('submit', async (event) => {
          event.preventDefault();
        
          const formData = new FormData(signupForm);
        
          const response = await fetch('/signup', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
              newUsername: formData.get('newUsername'),
              newEmail: formData.get('newEmail'),
              newPassword: formData.get('newPassword'),
            })
          });
        
          if (response.ok) {
            // Handle successful signup response
            const data = await response.json();
            console.log(data.message);
          } else {
            // Handle error response
            const error = await response.text();
            console.error(error);
          }
        });
        </script>
```

Yet i'm still not getting it in application/json.
It keeps sending it in application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Anyone knows why?

I tired changing the code like a million times but i still get the same problem.

Comment: If you look at the AJAX request in the Network tab, what does it show for Content-Type?

Comment: @Barmar I don't see anything in the XHR, but in my request headers the content-type is 
application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: If you don't see anything in the network tab how is it even making the request?

Comment: Your `headers` option is exactly as in the example [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#supplying_request_options) so I can't see any reason why you're not sending that header. Are you sure you deployed the code properly? Do you see the `headers:` option in the Sources tab?

Comment: Hey @Barmar, you helped me a lot your question made me look there and i  just had to move the script to the bottom as it wasnt getting the signup element.
Thank you

Comment: In that case you should have been getting an error in the browser's console saying that `signupForm` is null, so the event listener was never even fired.